# Last update broke WiFi connection on my Thinkpad E595

Tags: networking, wireless, updates

After updating system last night (to 21.10) I lost my wifi connection. The system GUI shows only bluetooth and something that looks like wifi, but probably is bluetooth instead (see the screenshot). Clicking on it only brings "Connection failed" message. `rfkill list all` only lists Bluetooth device:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

lshw -class network

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: f8:75:a4:cc:0a:ec
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-40-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.0.123 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:48 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d0904000-d0904fff memory:d0900000-d0903fff
```

How can I regain my connection?

Comment: Contact Lenovo and ask whether you need 'linux-tools-oem'.  If yes, you can install install from respository.

Comment: @robgrune Lenovo shows me that they do not support this model when I try to contact them via telephone and their webchat service is not working currently in my country, so no support from their side I am afraid.

Comment: I am seeing a number of other people posting problems with Lenovo machines. All I can think of is; you install the linux-tools- ;  if fail, do a fresh install; if fail, try a different distro, like Mint.  Note: at start of install, you should see the network icon at top bar. If not, then the machine does not support the distro out-of-the-box. A pity Lenovo will not support.

Comment: Get into UEFI/BIOS settings and try a reset to defaults